# TypeError: _webpack2.default.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin is not a function

Tags: webpack

Upgrading to webpack 2 I was faced with this error:

> TypeError: _webpack2.default.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin is not a function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [good news for webpack 2 is](https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7#occurrence-order):

> The plugin is no longer needed and occurrence order is on by default.

[Why it was breaking](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1964) is there was a spelling mistake which has been corrected and removed as a breaking change.

> OccurenceOrderPlugin has been renamed to OccurrenceOrderPlugin.

Comment: I am using webpack 1.15. After changing the `r` to `rr`, I still got the same error. Any idea why?